# Simplifying Summation

Tags: summation

> $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1} n = n^2/2 - n$$

A quick question on summation simplification that is not clear to me. In this case 
is multiplying $n$ by $n/2 -1$ valid? Or does it need to be plugged into $1/2(n(n+1))$?

Comment: Inserting mathjax has no reputation requirement.

Comment: Arguably, the above is only correct when $n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd then $i$ will not successfully reach the top, but instead will reach a maximum value of $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}-1\rfloor$ as $i$ is assumed to only take integer values, so the sum should instead simplify to $n\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor -n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the summand is $n$, a constant, and the lower bound is $0$. Thus, to find the sum, we multiply our summand $n$ by the upper bound $n/2-1$ to get the correct answer:

$$\frac{n^2}{2}-n$$

Comment: Ah ok. So only if the summand were $i$ would I need to use the formula? Also, the lower bound is zero in this case. Does that matter?

Comment: Exactly, if it were $i$ you'd need to use a formula.

$\\$

Oh, and that $1$ was a typo on my part. Regardless, lower bounds of $0$ and $1$ are interchangeable, so the answer provided is still correct (though its lower bound has been correctly altered from $1$ to $0$).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to consider $$A_n=\sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1} n=n \sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1}1$$ *hoping that I am not wrong*, you need to consider two cases.

If $n$ is even, set $n=2m$ and $$A_n=n \sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1}1=mn=\frac{n^2}2$$ If $n$ is odd, set  $n=2m+1$ and $$A_n=n \sum_{i = 0}^{m }1=(m+1)n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$